# Find files containing either character x or y?

Tags: bash

I know I can search for files using

```
find . -name *x*
```

...and this will find all files containing the `x` character. But how can I find all files containing either `[`, `]`, `*` or `?` characters?

Preferably, it would be nice to avoid duplicates so that I can pipe one and the same command to a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `glob` pattern in `find` command like this:

```
find . -name '*[][*?]*'
```

Above will find files that have any of these characters present in their names:

1. `]`
2. `[`
3. `*`
4. `?`

   - It is important to quote the pattern provided in `-name` option so that shell doesn't attempt to expand it.
   - Also important to keep `]` before `[` inside `[...]`

Comment: consider adding `-type f` if you don't want to list directories in your result set

Comment: Agreed, if OP wants to find only files not directories then `-type f` should be added.

Comment: You don't have to escape any of the characters in the bracket expression; `]` only needs to be escaped if it is not the *first* character (since `[]` is not a valid bracket expression, there is no ambiguity), and the rest are treated literally when part of a bracket expression. `-name '*[][*?]*'` is sufficient. (`[` might need to be quoted sometimes to avoid an unintentional character class, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner, that's good point, We can avoid escaping in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this trick:

```
find . * | grep -P "[\[\]*?]"
```

Comment: you can simply do `find` instead of `find . *`.  This will avoid printing everything twice - once with a `./` in front and once without. Also consider adding `-type f` to just look for file-names (and not directories)

Comment: Parsing the output of `find` subject to the same problems as parsing the output of `ls`; don't do it.

Comment: This will also spew out all files contained in directories that match the regex. This is quite different from the behavior of the command given in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`find` has `-regex or -iregex` option, it accepts regex. What you need is just building a simple regex expression.